# How do I account for a change of month using the DateTimePicker when comparing two Dates

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I am trying to create a basic hotel room booking app using windows forms and C#. I had initially started by creating the for loop on the grounds that the arrival date would always be smaller than the departure date. This all worked as expected until I tried to book a room for the 30th of June and depart on the 1st of July. As you can see from the code below, it will never enter the for-loop as the arrival date is not < than the departure date. I create a maxDays int which holds the max days that the person is going to stay and use that as the anchor for my loop. This probably boils down to a majority of logic issues and some foolish mistakes on my part since I have little to no experience using dates in my code. Any advice on this would be great.

```
private void CalculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Prints out number of nights at hotel.
        NumberOfNightsTextbox.Text = (DepartureDatePicker.Value.Day - ArrivalDatePicker.Value.Day).ToString("d");

        //Creates a copy of the current Arrival and Departure date.
        DateTimePicker ArrivalCopy = ArrivalDatePicker;
        DateTimePicker DepartureCopy = DepartureDatePicker;

        //Creates an int to store the current Arrival and Departure Month.
        int arrivalMonth = ArrivalDatePicker.Value.Month;
        int departureMonth = DepartureDatePicker.Value.Month;

        //Creates a int that is used to determine how many loops the For statement should loop for.
        //May need to add the monthly days after doing a check.
        int maxDays = DepartureDatePicker.Value.Day;

        //Gets the difference of the Arrival and Departure and converts it to an Int.
        double differnceD = (DepartureDatePicker.Value - ArrivalDatePicker.Value).TotalDays;
        int diff = (int)Math.Round(differnceD);

        if (arrivalMonth < departureMonth)
        {
            if (departureMonth == 1 || departureMonth == 3 ||
                departureMonth == 5 || departureMonth == 7 ||
                departureMonth == 8 || departureMonth == 10 ||
                departureMonth == 11)
            {
                diff += 31;

            }
            else if (departureMonth == 2)
            {
                diff += 28;

            }
            else if (departureMonth == 4 || departureMonth == 6 || departureMonth == 9 || departureMonth == 11)
            {
                diff += 30;

            }
        }
        if (arrivalMonth == departureMonth)
        {
            for (int i = ArrivalDatePicker.Value.Day; i < maxDays + 1; i++)
            {
                if (ArrivalCopy.Value.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || ArrivalCopy.Value.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
                {
                    increasePriceNight++;
                }

                ArrivalCopy.Value = ArrivalCopy.Value.AddDays(1);
            }
        }

        TotalPriceTextbox.Text = (((diff - increasePriceNight) * 120) + (increasePriceNight * 150)).ToString("C");

        AvgPricePerNightTextbox.Text = ((((diff - increasePriceNight) * 120) + (increasePriceNight * 150)) / diff).ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the total of days that the person is going to stay there. You can use this with the AddDays method to see if a day is Saturday or Sunday. For example

```
 for ( int i = 0; i <= maxDays; i++ )
        {
            DateTime date = ArrivalCopy.Value.AddDays( i );

            if ( date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday )
            {
                increasePriceNight++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Yup, I get that part alright, I am just having some issues with my logic on what to do if the departure date is in a different month which makes it a smaller value than the arrival date. Thanks for the comment tho!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you decided on such logic. You can do it much simplier

```cs
double days = (DepartureDatePicker.Value - ArrivalDatePicker.Value).TotalDays;
int daysTotal = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(days));
```

Basically, if the original `days` is something like 0.2 or 1.3, you just round this to the next integer. This is the number of days person must pay for.

And now, having number of days, you can iterate your `dates`, and add 1 day on each iteration and check what day of the week it is and charge proper charge - discount or upcharge

```cs
DateTeime startDate = ArrivalDatePicker.Value.Date;
decimal totalPrice = 0;
for (int dayNo = 0; dayNo < daysTotal;  dayNo++)
{
    DateTime currDate = startDate.AddDays(dayNo);
    totalPrice += GetPriceForDate(currDate);
}
```

In `GetPriceForDate` you investigate the date. What day of the week, what day of the month etc, and price it according to business rules.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! And yes, this was much simpler when it started, but as I ran into errors I just added lines without stepping back and maybe deciding a different approach. Ohh well, you live and learn.

Comment: @Kinetic I just edited a little bit. See if you like it

Comment: Hey, thanks for the update to, I took your advice on why would I bother with that logic and just changed it completely, your way made way more sense. Good learning experience though, cheers!

Comment: @Kinetic Glad it worked for you. Don't forget to accept the answer you like and up-vote as well, since it helps. Thanks